# How to output to iPhone's console?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm using Console.WriteLine() to output debug information. It gets shown in MonoDevelops output pane.
However it does not get displayed in the iPhone's console if the application is running on the device itself.
In ObjC "NSLog" seems to do the job, but what is the equivalent in MT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Console.WriteLine will show up in the iphone console, when not connected to the MonoTouch debugger.  When running in the debugger we redirect the output to MonoDevelop.

Comment: Strange. It does not show it. I will retry with the device not connected over USB. Will it also output in release builds?

Comment: Yes, it works in debug and release builds, it just matters if the debugger is connected, I just verified it works here.  Be aware tho the iPhone console output is NOT synchronous, and it will buffer output.

Comment: That's it. I got spoofed by the buffering.

Answer (score 1):

You can also see the console output in Xcode's organizer window.

Comment: Yes, that's what am referring to. There's the device's console log tab.